# How to Monitoring and Navigating URLs in Blazor Maui with Social Authentication

Tags: .net, maui, maui-blazor, maui-community-toolkit

I'm currently working on a Blazor Maui app using C# and integrating UAE Pass authentication. In my application, I need to monitor and navigate URLs within a Blazor page, such as Login.razor. I attempted to achieve this using an iframe, but encountered an error due to

Error_BlOCKED-BY-RESPONSE.

I'm looking for guidance on an alternative approach or a solution to monitor and navigate URLs within a Blazor page.

```
@page "/login" 
 <!-- My attempt with iframe --> 
<iframe src="@myUrl" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
  @code 
{    
 string myUrl = "https://stg-id.uaepass.ae/idshub/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sandbox_web_stage&scope=urn:uae:digitalid:profile:general&state=HnlHOJTkTb66Y5H&redirect_uri=https://stg-selfcare.uaepass.ae&acr_values=urn:safelayer:tws:policies:authentication:level:low"; 
}
```